Why don't we upvote questions on crypto?
Even when a perfectly fine question is asked it sometimes feels that I'm the only person voting it up. This even happens to questions like these. Now I guess the answer already had an upvote from SEJPM himself but I still think that we don't upvote questions enough here. Upvotes to questions already get half the points compared to answers; there's no need to make that gap larger.
Basically there are three major reasons for me not to upvote questions:

I don't understand the question (this happens too much :P );
I think the question is only useful to the person asking it;
The question does not show enough research.

I especially don't get it when a person answers a good question but still doesn't upvote it. Maybe the answer occupies all the brain cells required to upvote - I usually forget to upvote before answering as well. I do make amends afterwards though.
Anyway: we don't upvote questions enough. Please help me make good questions stand out!

Evidence people don't vote (on questions) a lot: there are only seven people with electorate but 54 with fanatic.

Funfact: I wasn't the first to upvote poncho's answer, but the second one. And I have to admit: my upvote ratio is nearly 4 : 1 for answers. :(

What may be the reason for people answering a question but not up-voting it, is that any of the above reasons may still apply (except for the first one maybe)

@SEJPM Whatever happens, your question probably will be upvoted quite a bit (messing up my example of course, but whatever :) ). Still, even now, the answer is upvoted in a 3:2 ratio compared to the question.

@MaartenBodewes I think you've found the solution to the problem, post a meta question about why questions aren't being upvoted :) For your next one, choose this question :) In all seriousness, as I've participated on other sites (crypto was my first), I've found that some of these other communities do upvote questions a lot better than we do, though maybe they are just larger? Not sure.

I guess people use the same criteria for deciding whether to upvote a question and and answer, and simply most questions are "worse" than the accompanying answer, when compared as this.

@otus These two sets do not overlap so the evidence is weak unfortunately.  Look the electorate rep  concentration.  They're mainly high rep experienced members with broad knowledge.  I'm a fanatic but don't up vote most questions because I don't understand the material.  My set can't judge most  questions' quality.  They're usually gobbledegook to me.  That's the crypto reason.  There are others.

@PaulUszak, my answer below has the more accurate (although old) comparison. If someone can up/downvote an answer they ought to be able to vote on the question as well.


…sometimes feels that I'm the only person voting it up. 

Trust me, I know the feeling. ;)
/* Just check our main site voting stats and our meta voting stats to see the top-10 voters. */

I especially don't get it when a person answers a good question but still doesn't upvote it. Maybe the answer occupies all the brain cells required to upvote…

Personally, I tried to blame “egos”, “lack of motivation”, “missing knowledge about the fact they can vote”, and some other things my brain tried to inject as a potential explanation. But nothing really fits. 
In the end, I settled with the conclusion that Crypto.SE members just don’t tend to vote that much. I’m just happy we get ample answers around here, which I always considered a prime priority for Crypto.SE. 
Nevertheless, I definitely agree that it can’t hurt to drop some votes every now and then.
An answer is just half the motivation for our members (especially the new ones) and a simple click on that upvote link can mean the world for someone starting out here… especially, since it helps to gain some basic priviledges new members need to earn so they can really suck the merrit out of this site.

… we don't upvote questions enough.

That’s my feeling too, which is why I think your call-for-action makes sense. Yet, I’ld like to expand it to a more general “we don’t (up)vote enough”.
As our meta voting stats and main site voting stats show, some of us surely do try to share their +1 whenever it makes sense… but it indeed seems as if only a small group of motivated people actually votes frequently. 
Maybe it’s time to remember voting is a social thing; a way of saying “thanks” and/or “I like it”. Everyone should try to do it every now and then. And there is no reason not to do so… after all, we’re talking about +1 votes here, and not those -1 votes people tend to avoid because they practically cost you a precious point or two.
TL;DR
Crypto.SE managed to graduate, now it’s time to work on the details to make this site even better by sharing opinions via (social) voting. Your vote is your voice… show members that their question or answer is a good one and that you appreciate the effort they’ve put into it. 

Upvoting only takes a single click – and comes with a free, nice feeling of having shared some kudos.

While I agree with e-sushi that votes in general could be more common, I think there's specifically a lack of voting on questions.
There are currently 18 people with more than 600 votes cast. Only eight of those have the electorate badge. (There were seven yesterday!) So ten of those 18 have voted more than 75% of the time on answers.
Question votes should be easy. You don't need to know much about the subject of the question to know that it is useful and worthy of an upvote. Or that it is unclear and poorly written, and requires a downvote. In contrast, I totally understand being hesitant to upvote even a good looking answer if you don't know enough to be entirely (or have time to make) sure it is correct.
Personally, I've cast a bit more votes on questions (~1200) than answers (~1000) precisely because even if I don't know enough about the topic to judge the validity of the answers (relatively common for me) I can often tell if the question is good, and almost certainly tell if it's very poor.

One recommendation I have is to avoid "No action needed" in the first posts review queue. Please vote one way or the other if it seems at all like a good idea.
